# using getOrElse in a play framework template

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I have an Option[Product] in my play 2 template.

Defined on Product is 'price'.

How can I check first that the Option is Some(p) and then access the price

```
@myproduct.price  // <- This obviously fails because myproduct is an Option[Product]

@myproduct.getOrElse("not found").price  // <- this does not work because price is not defined on the getOrElse.
```

I could use a messy match / case statement but would rather do it inline. Is there anyway this is possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `getOrElse` wrong. The value you pass to the `getOrElse` should be of type `Product` as well, applying `price` like you did would work then.

A solution would be to create a default `Product` that you would pass whenever you use `getOrElse`.

A better solution would be to use `map` instead, something like:

```
@myproduct.map { actualProduct =>
    actualProduct.price
}
```

This is generally used when you want to do something with your case class only if the `Option` is not `None`.